# reconstruct a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary that has 3 embedded layers, like below (there are many keys in each layer):

```
my_dict = {key1:{key2:{key3:some_value}}}
```

Now I want to reconstruct the dictionary by moving key3 as the very first layer. So the dictionary would look like:

```
my_dict = {key3:{key1:{key2:some_value}}}
```

I know the silly method of using 3 for loops to reconstruct the whole thing, like

```
my_new_dict = {}
for key1 in my_dict.keys():
    for key2 in my_dict[key1].keys():
        for key3 in my_dict[key1][key2].keys():
            ### a bunch of code to check if the key already exists and
            ### to move values into the new dictionary from scratch
```

I wonder if there are better ways to do it. Or maybe dictionary is not the best way to represent such data structure. Then what's a better way of constructing such data? I want to do the reconstruction because I want to do some computation that loops by key3 first, but I cannot get to key3 without looping with key1 and key2 first with my original dictionary.

Comment: I am not familiar with that one, what's the difference?

Comment: What *is* the data? Where do you get it from? Why is it structured that way to start with? Are there other uses for the data in its original structure? These questions are hard to answer well in the generic case.

Comment: describing the details of the data would take lots of time. but something similar as, key1 - male or female, key2, a bunch of departments, key3, different countries. values are a list of values of individuals in that country, in that dept, of that gender. The original dict was constructed because I was not a well-planned programmer :(. Now I want to pull out some country level stats. Later on I may want to get stats by gender, or by department, as we all know, research questions change all the time.

Comment: In that case, it might be worth putting the effort into making this a 4-D array (see e.g. [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/), or the experimental [`pandas.Panel4d`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/dsintro.html#panel4d-experimental)), then you can easily look at the dimensions you're most interested in.

Comment: Whatever you could try, you will have to fully walk through your 3 level directory so IMHO you cannot avoid the three loops to construct it. But what you describe really looks like a table in a database and sqlite is easy to use in Python. And then you will never have to wonder which is the top level directory ... but reconstructing your directories from scratch is not that hard.

Comment: Thanks all, I knew I was not using the best way to represent my data. :P will look into all the alternatives you guys suggested.

Comment: Quick tip, .keys() is redundant. By default: `for k in my_dict` will iterate over keys.

Comment: This is an area where using a database is better than a dictionary structured like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "bunch of code" doesn't actually need to be very complicated. If you use `dict.setdefault` to create new intermediate dictionaries as needed, the supposedly complicated part becomes a one-liner. I would also suggest iterating over the `items` of your dictionaries, rather than indexing them with the keys:

```
result = {}
for key1, middle_dict in my_dict.items():
    for key2, inner_dict in middle_dict.items():
        for key3, value in inner_dict.items():
            result.setdefault(key3, {}).setdefault(key1, {})[key2] = value
```

If you're using Python 2, you may want to use `iteritems` rather than `items`, as it doesn't allocate a list to hold all the values. In Python 3, `items` returns an iterable "view" object that doesn't require so much memory.

Answer (score 1):

Well it doesn't have to be that complicated, especially with defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
tree = lambda: defaultdict(tree)
new_dict = tree()
for key1 in my_dict:
    for key2 in my_dict[key1]:
        for key3 in my_dict[key1][key2]:
            new_dict[key3][key1][key2] = my_dict[key1][key2][key3]
```

The only problem is that you're now left with a bunch of defaultdicts, which have bad `__repr__`'s.